# WAMP/PHP Show Directory/Subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

How can I get my projects/virtual host links to show all the contents instead of looking directly for index.php?

If I click under "foo" I want to see all the folders and files in it if there is no index.php, instead of displaying an error.

I tried putting a .htaccess in the folder but I had no luck.

If there is a setting in a config file please let me know (I have already uncommented the header and rewrite module through the config file).

I would like something like what is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838665/wamp-directory-forbidden-error) to be shown when I click on a folder.

My htaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes 
DirectoryIndex disabled

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Error from the apache log: [core:alert] [pid 2984:tid 996] [client ::1:50836] C:/wamp64/www/Personal/.htaccess: Illegal option                                        I get this error when I simply try going to localhost or my other project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this in `.htaccess`:

```
Options +Indexes 
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

This will list the files in the directory instead of finding the index.

`Options +Indexes` will enable Directory Listing

`DirectoryIndex disabled` Disable DirectoryIndex, so that it will not find `index.php`, `index.html`, etc.

More information on `mod_dir` at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex.

Comment: Thanks luweiqi, I tried that and now I can getting an Internal Server Error (500). From what I saw online it is because of a commented out line (rewrite_module) and the header module, but mine is not commented out. I have tried restarting the server and restarted DNS, but it is still not working.

Comment: @Sakvad Thanks for the update, can you post the line in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: I have tried putting it in the folders of my projects but still have no luck. Yours had no space between "+" and Indexes, and I tried both with and without the space. The code is updated in my question.

Comment: Remove the `index.php` from the folder and see what happens.

Comment: @Ibu I cannot even access the localhost page successfully. I get the 404 page.

Comment: @Sakvad I've tested out the `.htaccess` code and the problem is with `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. If these 2 lines are commented out, then it works ;)

Comment: @luweiqi Something really strange is happening. The localhost page has a 404 error when one of my project folders is missing the htaccess. When both project folders have the htaccess the localhost page is error 500 (Internal Server Error) as are both project folders. Another strange thing I noticed is that the W for the WAMP icon is green, but there is a yellow background and what appears to be a little flame above the middle part of the W.